# How can I override styles of a local html page using Firefox userContent.css?

Tags: html, css

I'm using, to no avail, **@-moz-document url** within the file **userContent.css** to apply CSS rules in a specified URL. Here are the HTML and CSS code:

**HTML** (page.html)

```
...
<style type="text/css">
.mood {
    background: pink;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="mood">
    </div>
</body>
```

The **CSS** rule I added in userContent.css:

```
@-moz-document url (C:/Users/User/Documents/page.html) {
    .mood {
        background: red !important;
    }
}
```

I have other overriding rules in said **userContent.css** that do work if the specified URL is a website, e.g. **@-moz-document url (website.com)** For these other rules I don't have to write HTML code, though.

I also tried adding **file://**, **file:///**, **file://///** before the address: **(file://C:/...)** as I saw this suggested in an apparently related topic in http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work

Comment: Aren't `@-moz` useless since they only apply to the Firefox (Gecko) browsers which is [@ 4% of users in the world](https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share)? *"local html file"* is a broad term. Do you mean styles from `<link>`, `<style>`, and/or `.style` property? Assuming that `userContent.css` is from a `<link>` it's safe to assume that anything that proceeds it should override it.

Comment: @zer00ne Not useless at all if you, like I am, are in that 4%. I use Firefox because the other navigators I used, IE and Chrome, didn't allow me the good level of style customization Firefox allows via userContent.css and userChrome.css. By local html file I meant an html page (*.html) that is saved in my HDD.  I edited my question, I think it might answer the other questions you asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that legacy "toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets" flag enabled mentioned in this post?:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtfvS.png)

- https://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-can-i-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css

If you don't have that flag enabled... that's it

It looks like years ago Firefox guys disabled this by default (for start-up performance, shift in philosophy to avoid reading files during launch):
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1541233

Next idea... did you try with the word "domain" instead of "url"?
I'm also using userContent.css right now for just one tiny custom CSS for one of the websites I visit but never tried with local HTML file yet

```css
@-moz-document domain(homeserver.local) {
    .block-wrapper, .blue-block, .background-block .block-body {
        transform: scale(-1, 1);
        transition: 2s;
    }

    .polling-block {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```